# My question is on probability and and include populations percentages

Tags: probability

Question 1
On average, 2% of the population in an area die from HIV related illnesses per year. What is the probability that:
i. No person at all die from HIV related illnesses in any year?
ii. At least 2 people die from HIV related illnesses in a period of 2 years?

Comment: I have a feeling that for the first question, we would need some additional information. If the number is always between 1 and 3 per cent, then the answer would be zero per cent. For the second part, we would probably need to know how many people live in the area.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself? Will the population of the area affect the answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What work have you done to get to the answer already? You'll be more likely to get answers if you can show this.

Comment: I think (i) should be that no person dies in one particular given year